# Nodemailer error ,even if password and emailid is correct

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer, smtp-auth

I am developing an automatic email sender using nodeJs and nodemailer but encountered with this error.
Even if email id and password is correct nodemailer throws an error.
I have also enabled third party app access to gmail.

```
const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        host:"xyx",
        port:465,
        secure:true,
       auth:{
          user:"xyz@gmail.com",
          pass:"xyz"
       }
    });
    
    contactEmail.verify((error)=>{
        if(!error) console.log("Ready to send");
        else console.log(error);
    })
```

this gives me

```
    Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
      code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials gw20sm7224858pjb.3 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
```

Comment: Have you enabled "application passwords" or "less secure apps" in GMail? Are you using the application password (token) or your main password? Finally, are you sure you want to be using GMail as your automated e-mail platform?

Comment: Is there any better option than Gmail?

Comment: Yes - use a dedicated bulk-mailing service. Commercial services are offered by global providers such as SendGrid, Amazon, all the usual suspects. GMail is not a bulk e-mail service, but a consumer e-mail platform, so you can expect to be blocked after you send a few hundred messages.